# tortoisehg commit dialog focus on files from keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tortoisehg

when i launch the commit dialog (thg commit), the focus is on the commit message.  this is probably the most common place it should be.  in my case, i typically want to review the files i have changed and make sure i'm committing what i think i'm committing and not anything i don't intend.  the only way i have found to get to the file list to be able to use ctrl+d to view visual diffs is to use the mouse.  tabbing doesn't work because in the commit message input control, it just creates tab characters.

is there a way to use the keyboard and avoid the mouse altogether to move the focus to the list of files?

thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a quick skim through the source, and also had a look at the [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/KeySequences), and it seems there's no quick "official" way to do it.

One way I have found, which involves a lot of tabbing, is the following sequence:

```
$ thg commit
```

and when the window comes up, do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, which puts you into the "Regular Expression Search" box. Then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> a *lot* of times (10 when I just tried it, but it will vary), until you get into the file selection box.  Not great, but it sort of works... I do wonder if reaching for the mouse may be quicker, tho' :)

Comment: thanks very much for that.  certainly a creative answer.  i feared there was not going to be a way - this is almost as bad as not being a way, but thanks for coming up with what is probably the closest thing there is to a reasonable answer.  i'll leave this for another day or two to make sure nobody can find anything better and then accept this answer.  added a feature request - https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2522/commit-dialog-add-a-way-to-put-focus-on.  perhaps i'll try to implement this myself.

Comment: @DaveRael: In theory it should be quite a simple change (I don't really know the code, but looking at it it's quite straightforward). I would guess it would be part of a much larger change tho' - common keyboard shortcuts for all common window elements. Will keep an eye on the feature request :)